# Arduino interrupts interfering with TimeAlarms.h

Tags: arduino

I have and arduino sketch that needs to do several operations on a timed schedule using the TimeAlarms.h library. However, one of the operations, reading a hall sensor via interrupts, seems to interact poorly with the TimeAlarms library. 
I'm using the TimeAlarms library from here: http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_TimeAlarms.html 
And have adapted the hall sensor script from here: 
http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/G3/4_Water_Flow_sensor

I can run the hall sensor code on it own fine. However, when I try to run the hall sensor code along with `Alarm.timerRepeat` it hangs after entering the `check_flow` function.

Running the code below outputs only `enter CF` and then hangs. The same occurs if you try the `check_flow_alarm_delay` function instead, which uses the TimeAlarm version of Delay.

However, if you comment out `Alarm.timerRepeat(10, showseconds);` in setup
and `Alarm.delay(0);` in loop the hall sensor works fine.

Strangely, if you comment out `sei();` and `cli();` in the `check_flow` function the script works fine, and seems to count properly with the hall sensor. Why would this work? And should I be concerned that I'm not actively setting the time between `sei()` and `cli()`, leading to reliability issues in the sensor?

Note: you should be able to run the code without actually having a hall sensor, the output will just be 0 L/hr.

```
// reading liquid flow rate using Seeeduino and Water Flow Sensor from Seeedstudio.com
// Code adapted by Charles Gantt from PC Fan RPM code written by Crenn @thebestcasescenario.com
// http:/themakersworkbench.com http://thebestcasescenario.com http://seeedstudio.com

#include <Time.h>
#include <TimeAlarms.h>
#include <Wire.h>


volatile int NbTopsFan; //measuring the rising edges of the signal
int Calc;                               
int hallsensor = 2;    //The pin location of the sensor

void rpm ()     //This is the function that the interupt calls 
{ 
  NbTopsFan++;  //This function measures the rising and falling edge of the hall effect sensors signal
} 

void setup() //
{   
  Serial.begin(9600); //This is the setup function where the serial port is initialised,

  pinMode(hallsensor, INPUT); //initializes digital pin 2 as an input
  attachInterrupt(0, rpm, RISING); //and the interrupt is attached

  Alarm.timerRepeat(10, showseconds);

} 

void loop ()    
{
//  Serial.println( second() );

// stalls at enter CF
//  check_flow();

// stalls at enter CF
  check_flow_alarm_delay();

  Alarm.delay(0);
}

void showseconds ()
{
  Serial.println( second() );
}

void check_flow ()
{
  Serial.println("enter CF");
  int Calc;    
  NbTopsFan = 0;   //Set NbTops to 0 ready for calculations
//  sei();      //Enables interrupts
  delay(1000);   //Wait 1 second
//  cli();      //Disable interrupts
  Calc = (NbTopsFan * 60 / 5.5); //(Pulse frequency x 60) / 5.5Q, = flow rate in L/hour 

  Serial.print (Calc, DEC); //Prints the number calculated above
  Serial.print (" L/hour\r\n"); //Prints "L/hour" and returns a  new line 
}


void check_flow_alarm_delay ()
{
  Serial.println("enter CFAD");
  int Calc;    
  NbTopsFan = 0;   //Set NbTops to 0 ready for calculations
//  sei();      //Enables interrupts
  Alarm.delay(1000);   //Wait 1 second
//  cli();      //Disable interrupts
  Calc = (NbTopsFan * 60 / 5.5); //(Pulse frequency x 60) / 5.5Q, = flow rate in L/hour 

  Serial.print (Calc, DEC); //Prints the number calculated above
  Serial.print (" L/hour\r\n"); //Prints "L/hour" and returns a  new line 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delay()` uses interrupts. Disabling them interferes with the function.

Comment: This seems to be your problem. You 'll probably have to rewrite your code without using interrupts. See my reply (with sample code) to a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36382676/arduino-uno-r3-input-pins-with-gsm-shield/36392173